# How can I divide values into ranges in a group of columns grouped in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I receive data that I want to group according to ranges in a column chart, for example if I receive the number 1 as data, put the data in the column that stores the values from 1-5 in PowerBI, each column will have a range of values.example column1 range 1-5 column 2 range 6-10